# Xamarin Foms UWP Release Mode double variable will not set to zero

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, double, release

I have the following code:

```
 public static MapSpan GetMapspan(List<Position> pobj_Positions, bool pb_IncludeCurrentLocation)
    {

        bool gotRect = false;
        double ld_north = 0;
        double ld_west = 0;
        double ld_south = 0;
        double ld_east = 0;
        double ld_workLatitude = 0;
        double ld_workLongitude = 0;
        double ld_centerLatitude = 0;
        double ld_centerLongitude = 0;
        Position lobj_CenterPosition;
        MapSpan lobj_MapSpan = null;

        try
        {

            ld_north = 0;
            ld_west = 0;
            ld_south = 0;
            ld_east = 0;
            ld_workLatitude = 0;
            ld_workLongitude = 0;
            ld_centerLatitude = 0;
            ld_centerLongitude = 0;

            if (pobj_Positions.Count > 0)
```

So my challenge is that in release mode for my Xamarin Forms UWP app, when I get to the if statement seen below, ld_north and ld_east are not actually zero as they should be.  You can see their actual values below from the my watch window:

```
ld_north    6.237901216026427E-299  double
ld_west     0.0                 double
ld_south    0.0                 double
ld_east     7.8983449250911225E-299 double
```

Any idea how to fix this and or why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a 0 have this issue before, but for other numbers a double doesn't store its value exactly, there may be rounding errors. As you can see it has E-299, meaning its an incredibly small value.

If you need precision, move to a decimal.

Alternatively if you continue using doubles, you can check if its zero by doing

```
if (value < 0.00001 && value > -0.00001)
```

And you start checking things via a greater than or less than, rather than an absolute, to account for these issues.

The other issue it could be, is the Watch window is having a problem, even though it is actually zero, its hard to tell, but certainly could be a bug in the system. As I mentioned, I haven't seen an issue with a 0 before.